# Тире после "во-первых"

Tags: пунктуация

Может ли после "по-первых" (во-вторых и т.д.) ставиться не запятая, а тире? Ну, если это авторский знак. Или в таком случае должна быть и запятая, и тире? Или постановка тире вообще невозможна? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тире вместо запятой возможно в неполном предложении, где пропущен один из главных членов: Во-первых, я сегодня устал, во-вторых - голоден.